# Using Order By on Concatenated Column

Tags: oracle11g

I have a requirement where some columns from a table have to be grouped together to generate the result of the query. Sample query is as shown below:

```
SELECT COLUMN1 || '^' || COLUMN2 || '^' || DECODE(COLUMN3,'Y', 'YES', 'NO') || '^' || SUM(COLUMN4)
FROM MY_TABLE
GROUP BY COLUMN1, COLUMN2, DECODE(COLUMN3, 'Y', 'YES', 'NO');
```

I have a case where the order by positions are specified by the user in a comma separated sequence from the front end application. For example: 1,2 and different combinations of the column indexes depending on the user input.

I'm making use of oracle 11g as a database.

I require to perform order by on the columns numbers that are passed by the user. Eg:

```
SELECT COLUMN1 || '^' || COLUMN2 || '^' || DECODE(COLUMN3,'Y', 'YES', 'NO') || '^' || SUM(COLUMN4)
FROM MY_TABLE
GROUP BY COLUMN1, COLUMN2, DECODE(COLUMN3, 'Y', 'YES', 'NO')
ORDER BY 1, 2;  -----------<<< How should I be able to add the order by clause here dynamically
```

I get the following error on execution of the above query:

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
SELECT COLUMN1 || '^' || COLUMN2 || '^' || DECODE(COLUMN3,'Y', 'YES', 'NO') || '^' || SUM(COLUMN4)
FROM MY_TABLE
GROUP BY COLUMN1, COLUMN2, DECODE(COLUMN3, 'Y', 'YES', 'NO')
ORDER BY 1, 2
Error at Command Line:4 Column:16
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01785: ORDER BY item must be the number of a SELECT-list expression
01785. 00000 -  "ORDER BY item must be the number of a SELECT-list expression"
```

Please could anyone guide me on how I can add the order by part in this query!!!!!!

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve this in two ways.

1. Use same expression of group by/select in your order by.

   ```
   SELECT COLUMN1 || '^' || COLUMN2 || '^' || DECODE(COLUMN3,'Y', 'YES', 'NO') || '^' || SUM(COLUMN4)
   FROM MY_TABLE
   GROUP BY COLUMN1, COLUMN2, DECODE(COLUMN3, 'Y', 'YES', 'NO')
   ORDER BY COLUMN1 || '^' || COLUMN2 || '^' || DECODE(COLUMN3,'Y', 'YES', 'NO') || '^' || SUM(COLUMN4)
   ;
   ```
2. Use inner select and order by calculated name or numeric index

   ```
   SELECT * FROM ( 
   SELECT COLUMN1 || '^' || COLUMN2 || '^' || DECODE(COLUMN3,'Y', 'YES', 'NO') || '^' || SUM(COLUMN4)
   FROM MY_TABLE
   GROUP BY COLUMN1, COLUMN2, DECODE(COLUMN3, 'Y', 'YES', 'NO'))
   ORDER BY 1
   ```